# Will Asus M4A78LT-M support 3 monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I have this mother board: [Asus M4A78LTM](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A78LTM/).
I want to know if it will support 3 monitors. I actually tried to install all 3 and only 2 would display.

- Is there something I need to turn on in the BIOS to make this happen or does it just not support 3 monitors?
- If it does not support 3 monitors can I install a 2<sup>nd</sup> video card that would allow me to run 2 monitor from the motherboard and one from the card?

I looked at [the specs](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socketAM3/M4A78LT-M/E5232_M4A78LT-M_manual.zip) but it is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can have DVI + D-Sub or HDMI + D-Sub but not all three.

I'm also not sure about DVI + HDMI – I don't think this will work.

Yes, you should be able to install other graphics cards and use monitors on them.

Comment: Depending on the extra graphics card you can even do hybrid crossfire, using both the onboard GPU and the graphics cards GPU.

Or, when the extra graphics card is faster, you could plug two or three screens into that card and one of none in the onboard (AMD HD3000) graphics.